# How to reset Sublime Tutor?

Tags: sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

After modifying files in Sublime Tutor, how to reset them?
[Sublime Tutor](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Sublime%20Tutor)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove it:

- <kbd>ctrl+shift+p</kbd>
- `Package Control: Remove Package`
- `SublimeTutor`

Reinstall it:

- <kbd>ctrl+shift+p</kbd>
- `Package Control: Install Package`
- `SublimeTutor`

Done.